# What is the difference between mysqli_connect queries

Tags: php, mysqli

what is the difference between

1. `$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);`
2. `$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

**[mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) :**  Returns a string description of the last error

Above `$link` and $conn both variables are same carry connection object but in second `$conn` case when there is some error then connection die and generate mysqli last error

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between these two lines is that if you have mysqli error reporting switched off and the connection cannot be established, then the first `mysqli_connect` will return `null` and continue as if nothing happened, whereas the second one will kill the script and leak your sensitive credentials.

Do not use either one. The proper way to connect via mysqli class is this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$link->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

Three lines only, and no `die` or `if` statements.

First, you need to enable error reporting for mysqli, then you create the instance of this class, and lastly you set the correct charset.